# Can you generate Secondary Index DDL statements from an annotated class?

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-spanner

I'm currently generating "CREATE TABLE" statements by using the `SpannerShemaUtils.getCreateTableDdlStringsForInterleavedHierarchy(Class)`

Example

```
@Table(name = "#{@googleSpannerTablePrefix}Person")
public class Person {
   @PrimaryKey
   Integer personId;
   String name;
   Integer age;
}
```

Generate the create table DDL

```
SpannerShemaUtils.getCreateTableDdlStringsForInterleavedHierarchy(Person.class)
```

This produces

```
CREATE TABLE Person (  personId INT64 ,  name STRING(MAX) , age INT64 ) PRIMARY KEY ( personId );
```

If the @googleSpannerTablePrefix bean is set to "Example" it will generate this.

```
CREATE TABLE ExamplePerson (  personId INT64 ,  name STRING(MAX) , age INT64 ) PRIMARY KEY ( personId );
```

The @Table annotation allows sPel expressions (see above) so I can prefix my table names.

**Is there a way to generate Create index DDL statements in the same way?**

Answer (score 0):

I checked api document . https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Index.html
and following code may work. Could you try this?

```
@Table(name = "#{@googleSpannerTablePrefix}Person", 
    indexes=[@Index(name="#{@googleSpannerTablePrefix}Person_1", columnList="name")])
```

Comment: I'll check that out. Right now I'm using the org.springframework.cloud.gcp.data.spanner.core.mapping.Table annotation and it only has a "name" property.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my study of [SpannerSchemaUtils.java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spring-cloud-gcp/blob/main/spring-cloud-gcp-data-spanner/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/spring/data/spanner/core/admin/SpannerSchemaUtils.java), creating secondary indices using this class does not seem to be possible. The class only supports generating DDL statements for tables; i.e. there's no reference to handling table `index` in the code.

There is an open-source Github repo for this project; you may file a feature request in the Issue Tracker if you would like support for this: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spring-cloud-gcp/issues